# Pyspark create column based on whether or not value is in list

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I have a list column in a pyspark dataframe:

| colorList |
| --- |
| ["Red","Blue","Green","Black"] |
| ["Blue","Green"] |

How can I create columns with binary values based on whether or not a specific value is in that list column? Here's what the end result should look like:

| colorList | Red | Blue | Green | Black |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ["Red","Blue","Green","Black"] | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| ["Blue","Green"] | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 |

Answer (score 0):

You can do this dynamically using **`pivot`** and then `case when` statement.

**`Example:`**

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df = spark.createDataFrame([(["Red","Blue","Green","Black"],),(['blue','green'],)],['colorList'])

df =df.withColumn("colorList", expr("transform(colorlist, x-> lower(x))")).\
  select("colorList",posexplode(col("colorlist"))).\
    groupBy("colorList").pivot("col").agg(first(col("pos")))

df.select('colorList',
          *[when(col(f"{f}").isNull(),lit(0)).otherwise(lit(1)).alias(f) for f in df.columns if f not in ['colorList']]).\
  show(10,False)
#+-------------------------+-----+----+-----+---+
#|colorList                |black|blue|green|red|
#+-------------------------+-----+----+-----+---+
#|[blue, green]            |0    |1   |1    |0  |
#|[red, blue, green, black]|1    |1   |1    |1  |
#+-------------------------+-----+----+-----+---+
```

Answer (score 0):

Explode the array column and do pivot.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f

data = [
    ["Red","Blue","Green","Black"],
    ["Blue","Green"]
]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ArrayType(StringType())).toDF('colorList')

df.select(f.col('colorList'), f.explode('colorList').alias('color')) \
  .groupBy('colorList') \
  .pivot('color') \
  .count() \
  .fillna(0) \
  .show(truncate=False)

+-------------------------+-----+----+-----+---+
|colorList                |Black|Blue|Green|Red|
+-------------------------+-----+----+-----+---+
|[Blue, Green]            |0    |1   |1    |0  |
|[Red, Blue, Green, Black]|1    |1   |1    |1  |
+-------------------------+-----+----+-----+---+
```